# What real-time operating systems are supported by the Raspberry pi 3 model B?

Tags: operating-systems, real-time, freertos

I have been looking around for multiple RTOS for the rpi3 but unfurtunately many of them are not (yet?) supported?

Could anybody tell me which ones can be used on the rpi3 now?

Comment: I'm not sure if the MachineKit project is of any use, http://www.machinekit.io/docs/getting-started/installing-packages/ they have a real-time kernel that can be used on the Pi, although possibly only the Pi2 is supported.

Comment: What features of the RTOS are you going to use?  Presumably not all RTOS will have implemented the features which are important to your application.

Comment: @joan Idk yet. This will be the first time I will use an RTOS. So so far I am open to any RTOS that works on rpi3 model b.

Comment: I'd recommend against asking your question cross communities so quickly. Electronics migrated your other question here, which I've deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used it, and I think it does not qualify as a true RTOS, but if you want a platform on which a process can run uninterrupted for an arbitrary length of time, I believe [RISC OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RISC_OS) can deliver that (beware "RISC" also refers to an abstract sort of ISA on which ARM processors are based).

As per the wikipedia page, RISC OS uses *[cooperative multi-tasking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_multitasking)*:

> ...a style of computer multitasking in which the operating system never initiates a context switch from a running process to another process. Instead, processes **voluntarily yield control** periodically or when idle

By implication you can voluntarily not yield control.  I don't know how feasible this is if you intend to have a long running process never preempt itself, but perhaps you actually do not need to go that far.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this link might be of some use to you.
http://www.valvers.com/open-software/raspberry-pi/step01-bare-metal-programming-in-cpt1/

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help). Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it is preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. In fact we're [enforcing this policy](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/842/5538): please edit so that the answer stands on its own should the link break in the future. If it is not edited within 48 hours it will be converted to Community Wiki.